# tabular with a 2-row multirow for document heading fields

Tags: tables, fancyhdr

I'm trying to make a heading of a document that looks like the following:
[image: table in lowriter]

My try is at the bottom, here are my requirements:

-- the fields on the right must be left aligned but at the rightmost of the document. That is the reason why I put an empty column in the middle.

-- the content of the table must be aligned from the top like in the picture. I might also need to add inner margins to the cells of the table since from the code below in the output pdf file the content of the cell 2nd column, 2nd row crosses over the cell upper boundary. Note that the horizontal bar between the two cells of the right must rather be for decoration and standing in the middle of the space between the upper text and the lower text. Not like I did in the code. It looks more like underlining the last line of the upper cell content.

So far what I did is only by grabbing here and there on the web. The most important is the what is in the picture and the requirements. Feel free to make the code as concise, neat, and efficient as possible. Even for the font, if you have any better sf font, change it.

so far what i did is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot,a4paper, textwidth=0.70\paperwidth, textheight=0.8\paperheight}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{%
\itshape document header here
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lll}
  \multirow[t]{2}{*}{%
    \shortstack[l]{
    \textbf{address}\\
    1st street here\\
    1, city's best street\\
    worst area, nowhere 123123}}

  & & \shortstack[l]{\textbf{contact 1}\\
    his name, another city\\tel. 123098723}\\\cline{3-3}
  & &\\

  & & \shortstack[l]{\textbf{contact 2}\\
    another's name, another city\\tel. 123098722}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two separate tabulars and `\hfill` inbetween them:

[image]

(Red lines indicate textblock/margins/header position)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot,a4paper, textwidth=0.70\paperwidth, textheight=0.8\paperheight}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{%
\itshape document header here
}


\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{address}\\
    1st street here\\
    1, city's best street\\
    worst area, nowhere 123123
   \end{tabular}
\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{contact 1}\\
    his name, another city\\
    tel. 123098723\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{contact 2}\\
    his name, another city\\
    tel. 123098723
   \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```